# Python Parsing key=value from string

Tags: python, parsing

I have string like this:

```
[KEY1=ABC, KEY2=ABC, ... , KEY3={KEY123=ABC, KEY456=ABC}, KEY111=ABC, KEY4=KEY=VALUE&KEY=VALUE&KEY=VALUE]
```

I want to parse it into a python dict like this

```
dict = {
   'KEY1': 'ABC',
   'KEY2': 'ABC',
   'KEY3': '{KEY123=ABC, KEY456=ABC}',
   'KEY111': 'ABC',
   'KEY4': 'KEY=VALUE&KEY=VALUE&KEY=VALUE',
}
```

Note that, the values can contain complex/special chars like `/\-@'"`

In case 'KEY4'; It can be like a URL GET String format. Example

```
KE4=id=1&username=xx&url=http://xxx...&ref=1
```

The following code partially works. It does not parse Values that contains nested key=val. like 'KEY3' above

```
dict = builtins.dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)=(".*?"|\S+)', input))
```

Comment: So the input is the actual string `'[KEY1=ABC, KEY2=ABC, KEY3={KEY123=ABC, KEY456=ABC}, KEY111=ABC]'` ?

Comment: yes like this format

Comment: Do you really want the `KEY3=` in the `KEY3` value?  It's absent from the other entries.

Comment: no;    'KEY3': '{KEY123=ABC, KEY456=ABC}', I modified my question. thanks for pointing this

Comment: Anytime I see weird ad-hoc input formats, I first try to see if it can be changed to something more standard, rather than having to write an ad-hoc parser for it.

Comment: Well, regex probably won't work since it has nesting; you'll need to make a parser. Though you might be able to hijack another parser, like `json.loads()` or `ast.literal_eval()`, if you can get it into a format they'd understand.

Comment: @wjandrea The obvious choice here is `configparser`

Comment: @DeepSpace Because of the equals sign and unquoted key/values?

Comment: @wjandrea Indeed

Comment: Why do you want `'{KEY123=ABC, KEY456=ABC}'`? Why not parse it too? i.e. `{'KEY123': 'ABC', 'KEY456': 'ABC'}`

Comment: @wjandrea I just need to parse as the format mentioned in the question. because this is logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your (slightly edited) regex in a function that you can call on the dictionary values to transform nested strings in dictionary as well:

```
import re
import json

input_str = "[KEY1=ABC, KEY2=ABC, KEY3={KEY123=ABC, KEY456=ABC}, KEY111=ABC]"

def dict_from_str(s):
    return dict(re.findall(r'(\w+)=([^{]*?|\{.*?})(?:,|$)', s.strip('[]{}')))

dict_out = dict_from_str(input_str)

for k, v in dict_out.items():
    if '=' in v:
        dict_out[k] = dict_from_str(v)

print(json.dumps(dict_out, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "KEY1": "ABC",
    "KEY2": "ABC",
    "KEY3": {
        "KEY123": "ABC",
        "KEY456": "ABC"
    },
    "KEY111": "ABC"
}
```

If you have more levels, you could consider writing a recursive function.

Edit: you can handle URLs separately (note that the keys must be unique, unlike your first example):

```
input_str = "[KEY1=ABC, KEY2=ABC, KEY3={KEY123=ABC, KEY456=ABC}, KEY111=ABC, KEY4=KEY=VALUE&KEY2=VALUE&KEY3=VALUE]"

def dict_from_str(s):
    return dict(re.findall(r'(\w+)=([^{]*?|\{.*?})(?:,|$)', s.strip('[]{}')))

def dict_from_url(s):
    return dict(re.findall(r'(\w+)=([^=]*?)(?:&|$)', s.strip('[]{}')))

dict_out = dict_from_str(input_str)

for k, v in dict_out.items():
    if '&' in v:
        dict_out[k] = dict_from_url(v)
    elif '=' in v:
        dict_out[k] = dict_from_str(v)

print(json.dumps(dict_out, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "KEY1": "ABC",
    "KEY2": "ABC",
    "KEY3": {
        "KEY123": "ABC",
        "KEY456": "ABC"
    },
    "KEY111": "ABC",
    "KEY4": {
        "KEY": "VALUE",
        "KEY2": "VALUE",
        "KEY3": "VALUE"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great! Only one issue; it can't parse a value if it's like this (URL Params example): key_params=user=a&id=1&url=xxxx&date=xxx&type=xxx. Can you please fix it. Thanks

Comment: That's not the same format as in your question... Could you update it? What's the expected dictionary in this case? The regex pattern in this case would prob look like `r'(\w+)=([^=]*?)(?:&|$)'`

Comment: I tried  r'(\w+)=([^=]*?)(?:&|$)' but the a lot of content is missing now. First solution works but just want to parse also values like this: KE4=id=1&username=xx&url=http://xxx...&ref=1